# How do I remove an array elements from another array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array. How do I remove all those elements which are present in another array i.e. `$remove` and re-index the final array starting from 1 not 0?

```
  $info =  array(
    '1' => array('name' => 'abc', 'marks' => '56'),
    '2' => array('name' => 'def', 'marks' => '85'),
    '3' => array('name' => 'ghi', 'marks' => '99'),
    '4' => array('name' => 'jkl', 'marks' => '73'),
    '5' => array('name' => 'mno', 'marks' => '59')
  );
  $remove = array(1,3);
```

Desired Output:

```
  $info =  array(
    '1' => array('name' => 'def', 'marks' => '85'),
    '2' => array('name' => 'jkl', 'marks' => '73'),
    '3' => array('name' => 'mno', 'marks' => '59')
  );
```

So far I've tried these two methods. Nothing worked for me.

```
  if (($key = array_search(remove[0], $info))) {
    unset($info[$key]);
    $info = array_values($info);
  }
```

And

```
  $result = array_diff($info, $remove);
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the array as an associated array like that with specified keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
$result = array_diff_key( $info, array_flip( $remove));
```

This [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/array_flip)s your `$remove` array so the keys become the values and the values becomes the keys. Then, we do a difference against the keys with [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/array_diff_key) of both arrays, [to get this result](http://viper-7.com/PNzOJZ):

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => def
            [marks] => 85
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => jkl
            [marks] => 73
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => mno
            [marks] => 59
        )

)
```

Finally, to yield your exact output, you can reindex your array by passing it through [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values), but this will yield sequential indexes starting at zero, not one:

```
$result = array_values( array_diff_key( $info, array_flip( $remove)));
```

If you *really* need indexes to start at one, you will need a combination of [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine) and [`range()`](http://php.net/range):

```
$result = array_diff_key( $info, array_flip( $remove));
$result = array_combine( range( 1, count( $result)), $result);
```

Comment: And then re-index the keys (starting from 1 somehow) and you're done ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about using [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function?

**Example**

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

**this will output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```