# Get random from one PHP array but not match from another

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in PHP: big and small. All the values in small arrays are included in big array. I need to get random value from big array but it will be not matched with any value of small array. Something like:

```
$big = array('2','3','5','7','10');
$small = array('2','5','10');
$random = '3'; // it's not 2, 5 or 10
```

Comment: [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) with an `if`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327137/how-do-i-remove-an-array-elements-from-another-array How about removing the small array from the big array and picking a random value from the resulting items?

Comment: [Try the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `array_diff()` to determine the difference - and pick a random number (using `mt_rand()`) from the resulting array:

```
$arrDiff = array_values(array_diff($big, $small));
$random = $arrDiff[mt_rand(0, count($arrDiff)-1)];
```

Note: the `array_values()` method makes sure that only the values are copied to the array  `$arrDiff`, so the indexes from `0...n-1` are filled with values.`array_diff()` will maintain the index-positions, so there might be no index `0`, `1` or whatever, as stated by @Undefined-Variable.

Comment: Is there a function called `random()` ?

Comment: There is an error in your answer - array_diff retains the key original key indices - thus if you randomly select a key index between 0 and count, it might not exist.

Comment: @UndefinedVariable valid point. Added `array_values` to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

```
$big = array('2','3','5','7','10');
$small = array('2','5','10');

$nums = array_diff($big,$small);//numbers in big that are not in small
$rand = array_rand($nums); //get a random key from that set
$val = $nums[$rand]; //get the value associated with that random key
```

Comment: "min/max" will work on the values, not on the keys. so, this will return a random between 3 and 7 - which is not what op wants, cause for instance "6" is possible but not part of any array.

Comment: Yes, @dognose is right, solution by raidenace doesn't work if $big = array('7','2','10','5','3'); i.e. digits of array has random order

Comment: @user3892905 - `array_rand` returns a `random key` from the array. In order to get the value you have to query using that random key like : `$nums[$rand]`. It doesnt have anything to do with random order of digits. I have updated answer just for clarity

Comment: for further reader: My prior comment refered to the first version of the post which has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bigs = ['1', '2', '3', '5', '10'];
    $small = ['1', '5', '10'];

    foreach($bigs as $big)
    {
        if(!in_array($big, $small))
        {
            echo $big. "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: this just echos all the unique array values. also, under normal circumstances, `\n` will not break the line unless you send plaintext headers to the browser.

Comment: i just echoed it out so he could see the values being returned, I wouldn't actually return it like this @Adelphia

Comment: this is basically just a more complicated array_diff() anyways.